# RecyclerView ItemClick to Detail Activity is not working

Tags: android, json, android-intent, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I have implemented a recyclerView in my app. I parse the data from a local json which stored in assets folder. Now I can see the parsed data in recyclerview. I have created another Activity which will show the detail activity of this recyclerview. to see this deatil I have implemented onItemClick listener method. but unfortunately this method is not working in my app. I do not know how to solve this issue in case of recyclerview.

My ItemClickListener interface is

```
public interface ItemClickListener {
void onItemClick(int pos);
}
```

My Adpater Class is

```
public class MyColleaguesAdapter extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<MyColleaguesAdapter.ColleagueHolder> {


private List<MyColleageModel> colleagueObject;
private Context context;

public MyColleaguesAdapter(List<MyColleageModel> colleagueObject, Context context) {

    this.colleagueObject = colleagueObject;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public ColleagueHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.colleage_row_layout,parent,false);
    return new ColleagueHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ColleagueHolder holder, int position) {
    final MyColleageModel myColleague=colleagueObject.get(position);
    //holder.colleaguePicture.setImageResource(myColleague.getImageResourceId());
    holder.mobile.setText(myColleague.getMobile());
    holder.mail.setText(myColleague.getMail());
    holder.name.setText(myColleague.getName());
    holder.company.setText(myColleague.getCompany());
    holder.department.setText(myColleague.getDepartment());
    holder.title.setText(myColleague.getTitle());

    //do not know how to implement it
    holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int pos = (int)
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return colleagueObject.size();
}
////open activity
private void openDetailActivity(String...details)
{
    Intent i=new Intent(context,DetailMyColleague.class);
    i.putExtra("mobile",details[0]);
    i.putExtra("mail",details[1]);
    i.putExtra("name",details[2]);
    i.putExtra("company",details[3]);
    i.putExtra("department",details[4]);
    i.putExtra("title",details[5]);
    context.startActivity(i);
}


public class ColleagueHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
    public CardView cardView;
    public ImageView colleaguePicture;
    public TextView mobile;
    public TextView mail;
    public TextView name;
    public TextView company;
    public TextView department;
    public TextView title;
    ItemClickListener itemClickListener;

     public ColleagueHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        //colleaguePicture=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.drawable.profile_image);
        mobile=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.colleague_mobile);
        mail=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.colleague_mail);
        name=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.colleague_name);
        company=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.company_name);
        department=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.department_name);
        title=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.job_title);
        cardView=(CardView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.cvSingleUser);
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        this.itemClickListener.onItemClick(this.getLayoutPosition());
    }
    public void setItemClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener)
    {
        this.itemClickListener=itemClickListener;
     }
   }

 }
```

My Main Activity Class is

```
public class MyColleaguesPage extends AppCompatActivity{

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
private List<MyColleageModel> colleagueObject;
InputStream is;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mycolleagues_layout);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.colleagues_recycler);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(MyColleaguesPage.this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    new JSONTask().execute();

}



    public class JSONTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, List<MyColleageModel>> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected List<MyColleageModel> doInBackground(String... params) {

        colleagueObject = new ArrayList<MyColleageModel>();

        try {

            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(loadJSONFromAsset());
            JSONArray m_jArry = obj.getJSONArray("contacts");
            MyColleageModel my_clg;

            for (int i = 0; i < m_jArry.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jo_inside = m_jArry.getJSONObject(i);
                //my_clg=new MyColleageModel();
                String val1 = jo_inside.getString("mobile");
                String val2 = jo_inside.getString("mail");
                String val3 = jo_inside.getString("name");
                String val4 = jo_inside.optString("company");
                String val5 = jo_inside.optString("department");
                String val6 = jo_inside.optString("title");
                my_clg = new MyColleageModel(val1, val2, val3, val4, val5, val6);
                colleagueObject.add(my_clg);
            }


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final List<MyColleageModel> result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

            adapter = new MyColleaguesAdapter(colleagueObject, getApplicationContext());
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


    }
 }

   private String loadJSONFromAsset() {
    String json = null;
    try {

        is = getAssets().open("colleagues.json");

        int size = is.available();

        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];

        is.read(buffer);

        is.close();

        json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");


    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    return json;

   }
}
```

My Detail Activity Class is

```
public class DetailMyColleague extends AppCompatActivity {


private TextView jsonName;
private TextView jsonRole;
private TextView jsonCompany;
private TextView jsonMobile;
private TextView jsonEmail;
private TextView jsonDepartment;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.colleague_detail);

    // Showing and Enabling clicks on the Home/Up button
    if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    }
    // setting up text views and stuff
    setUpUIViews();

    Intent intent = getIntent();

    //RECEIVE DATA
    String mobil=intent.getExtras().getString("mobile");
    String mail=intent.getExtras().getString("mail");
    String name=intent.getExtras().getString("name");
    String company=intent.getExtras().getString("company");
    String dept=intent.getExtras().getString("department");
    String title=intent.getExtras().getString("title");
    //BIND DATA
    jsonMobile.setText(mobil);
    jsonEmail.setText(mail);
    jsonName.setText(name);
    jsonCompany.setText(company);
    jsonDepartment.setText(dept);
    jsonRole.setText(title);

}

private void setUpUIViews() {

    jsonName=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.json_name);
    jsonRole=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.json_role);
    jsonCompany=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.json_company);
    jsonMobile=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.json_mobile);
    jsonEmail=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.json_email);
    jsonDepartment=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.json_department);
}
```

}

Comment: Why would you create your own onClickInterface?

Comment: @MartinDeSimonen I am very new in android developing. I have read one artcle and then try to implement it. but nothing happen when I click on the item. Could you plaese explain why is it happening. I stuch with this issue from morning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you have not set OnClickListener on any of your View, as a result, the onClick() method will never be triggered, hence no callback to your onItemClickListener will be sent.

Secondly, you don't need to implement an interface for this, you can simply set the onClickListener inside onBindViewHolder() method just like this:

```
holder.cardView.setTag(position);

holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        int pos = (int)view.getTag()
    openDetailActivity(myColleague.getMobile(),myColleague.getMail(), myColleague.getName(),
            myColleague.getCompany(), myColleague.getDepartment(), myColleague.getTitle());

    }
});
```

here am using setTag() method to send the current position to onClick() method for referencing the view that was clicked.

write this line inside ViewHolder class to get CardView reference in your case.

```
cardView=(CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardview_id);
```

Comment: what do you mean by viewIWantToClick.?

Comment: this is the view object, that get's clicked, if you want to make the whole item clickable then get the reference of parent layout from the xml and set onclick listener on it. for testing you can set the clicklistener on any view, for instance title

Comment: I have a cardview. I want to click on that cardview. not the single item  like name, role, department etc

Comment: Shall I declare this Cardview inside holder class?

Comment: yes, that's how it's' done. All the views being used in a recycler view item are declared in ViewHolder class.

Comment: what can I set here the object "mobile ", "Name" in holder.cardView.setTag();

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149332/discussion-between-ravinder-bhandari-and-ktina).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply setOnClickListener to your holder's parent layout i.e RelativeLayout or LinearLayout, etc.

```
holder.relative_layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            openDetailActivity(myColleague.getMobile(),myColleague.getMail(), myColleague.getName(),
                myColleague.getCompany(), myColleague.getDepartment(), myColleague.getTitle());

        }
    });
```

Comment: Could you plaese explain what is relative_layout here?

Comment: Whatever your parent layout is, for eg. all the view items in your ColleagueHolder, i.e all your TextViews, ImageViews are under one parent layout, you have to set an onClickListener to that layout.

Comment: yes I have a colleague_row_layout- But how can I decalre it here?

Comment: No, colleague_row_layout may be the name of your xml file. Consider below example, here is the xml file, the outer most xml tag is the parent layout in this - [code for xml file](https://github.com/hsm59/droidTunes/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/song_item.xml) in this file, the parent layout is <RelativeLayout>

Comment: I stuch with the issue. but could get how can I do that

Comment: if you are using a CardView, use the ID of the CardView and setOnClickListener on the CardView. for eg. holder.card_view.setOnClickListener()..

Comment: Shall Idecrare tis cardview inside the holder class?